# context menu in opera browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a context menu option in opera browser but it appears always when I right click .

My Question :

I want it to how to appear on right click only when there is a audio or video stream on the web page how can I do this?

Here is the code for background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Download via bytesloader",
  contexts: ["all"],
  onclick: bytesloader
});

function bytesloader() {
  var myQuery = "https://www.savefromnet.com/";
  chrome.tabs.create({
   url: myQuery
  });
}
```